# How to use django-compressor with multiple LESS files that import common files?

Tags: css, django, less, django-compressor

I have organized the templates in my Django project in such a way that each page on the site includes a "common" LESS file and each page can also specify another LESS file that includes page-specific styles.

The problem is that I need the page-specific LESS file to be able to refer to variables in the "common" LESS file. The easiest way of doing this, I thought, was to simply move variable declarations into a separate file that both LESS files could `@import`.

However, Django apps use separate directories for storing their static files. In the end, the filesystem looks something like this:

```
- common
   - static
      - css
         - definitions.less
         - common.less
- other
   - static
      - css
         - other.less
```

Both `common.less` and `other.less` need to import `definitions.less`. In the case of `common.less` this is as simple as:

```
@import "definitions.less";
```

Here is how the LESS files are actually included on the page, just in case that helps:

```
{% load compress %}
{% load static %}

{% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static "css/common.less" %}"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/less">
{% endcompress %}
```

What would be the easiest way to ensure common variable definitions are available to both LESS files? I want to avoid combining the LESS files for a couple of reasons:

- It removes the benefits of loose-coupling (the ability to deactivate an app without any side effects on the rest of the site).
- The additional data being retrieved for a single page is increased since all styles for all apps must be fetched.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have encountered this same problem

Comment: Any word on solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing in our app -- we have a common file main.less that is included by many of the other less files. However, we dont run into this issue. I think there are a few ways around it-- you could change the location of your static files.

There is a setting in django STATICFILES_DIRS -- and it seems you could change the location of your static files if you want instead of being nested in apps like that.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Our code looks like this

```
{% compress css %}
{% include "_base_css.html" %}
{% endcompress %}
```

And then _base_css.html just includes all the less files, with our main.less coming first.

```
## _base_css.html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.less">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/about.less">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/dashboard.less">
```

It's not clear to me from your question what the error is, but I believe your common less file needs to be included before any other less file to be accessible. In your code snippet it doesnt seem like you include that. In terms of compressing, I dont think compressing all of your sitewide css into one file is too bad -- it is one download the first time and then is fully cached.

Hope this was helpful.